# Why does this not compile in F#

Tags: f#, recursion

This compiles and works:

```
let rec HelloEternalWorld _ = 
  Console.ReadLine() |> printf "Input: %s\n"
  HelloEternalWorld 0

HelloEternalWorld 0
```

This does not compile:

```
let rec HelloEternalWorld = 
  Console.ReadLine() |> printf "%s\n"
  HelloEternalWorld

HelloEternalWorld
```

I try to understand why not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you're missing are parentheses, as it would compile if it were:

```
let rec HelloEternalWorld() = 
  Console.ReadLine() |> printf "%s\n"
  HelloEternalWorld()
```

To define a function with no arguments you need the parentheses to distinguish the function from a simple value.

Answer (score 4):

Please post the error messages you get, they say everything you need!

> The value ... will be evaluated as part of its own definition.

Your code doesn't compile because you're declaring a recursive value (which doesn't exist) instead of a recursive function.

In order to make this a function, you'll have to write something like

```
let rec HelloEternalWorld() = 
  Console.ReadLine() |> printfn "%s"
  HelloEternalWorld()
```

which is now a function of type `unit -> unit`.